# why HashSet is good for search operations?

Tags: collections, hashset

hashset underlaying data structure is hashtable .how it will identify duplicates and why it is good for if our frequent operation is search operation ?

Comment: *"how it will identify duplicates and why it is good for if our frequent operation is search operation ?"* .. Going out a limb here, but .... well ... because it uses hashes??

Answer (score 0):

It uses hash code of the object which is quickly computed integer. This hash code tries to be as even distributed over all potential object values as possible.

As a result it can distribute the inserted values into a array (hashtable) with very low probability of conflict. Then the search operation is quite quick - get the hash code, access the array, compare and get the value - usually constant time. The same actually happens for finding duplicates.

The conflicts of hash code are resolved as well - there can be potentially more values for the same entry within the hash table - there comes the equal into play. But they are rather rare so they don't affect average performance significantly.